# Using MergeMap with the array of data received from another observable - RxJs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a fetchDrives method which will return an observable which on subscription will return a list of drives

```
this.fetchDrives(points).subscribe(drives => {
     console.log(drives);
});
```

Assume The drives array which I got on subscription look some what like this

```
[ {driveId: 1}, {driveId: 2}, {driveId: 3} ]
```

Now I need to use the driveId one by one and make three calls ( three because length of the drives array is 3 ) by passing driveId to each api call.I need to pass driveId to the below method one at a time and get the lat and lon and store the result of three calls in an array.

```
this.getLatLong(driveId).subscribe( res => console.log(res))
```

The res will contain an object like `{ lat: 12, lon: 54 }`

I don't want to do two subscriptions, is there a way I can use the Rxjs operators and achieve this with one subscription using the result of previous observable, loop through the drives array and make three calls to `getLatLong` method using `mergeMap` as the sequence of the calls doesn't matter and store the result of those three calls in an array?

I tried using scan operator to loop through but failed to use it to get the desired output

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the requests doesn't matter, you could use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) method to make the calls simultaneously. I've also used [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to switch the observable once the source observable (`this.fetchDrives(points)`) emits. Try the following

```js
locations: any;

this.fetchDrives(points).pipe(
  switchMap((drives) => {
    let source = Object.create(null);
    for (let i = 0; i < drives.length; i++) {
      source[drives[i]['driveId']] = this.getLatLong(drives[i]['driveId']);
    }
    return forkJoin(source);
  })
).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.locations = response;
  },
  error => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

Variable `locations` will be of the form

```
// 'driveId': { lat: 12, lon: 54 }

{
  '1': { lat: 12, lon: 54 },
  '2': { lat: 12, lon: 54 },
  '3': { lat: 12, lon: 54 }
}
```

#### Update: array of objects output

To return an array of objects from `forkJoin` you could send in an array of observables as the argument. For eg. `forkJoin([obs1, obs2, ...])`. In the previous case we were sending an object as the argument (`forkJoin({'name1': obs1, 'name2': obs2, ...})`, so the output will also be an object.

```js
locations: any = [];

this.fetchDrives(points).pipe(
  switchMap((drives) => {
    return forkJoin(drives.map(drive => this.getLatLong(drive['driveId'])));
  })
).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.locations = response;
  },
  error => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

`locations` will be of the form

```
[
  { lat: 12, lon: 54 },
  { lat: 12, lon: 54 },
  { lat: 12, lon: 54 }
]
```

Comment: I overlooked a key part in the argument to the `forkJoin` function. I was sending an array of objects instead of one single object. I've edited the answer. Please try the new version.

Comment: Michael the desired output is an array of objects, and I believe forkJoin will do that trick

Comment: I've updated the answer. In that case you could do `forkJoin(drives.map(drive => this.getLatLong(drive['driveId'])))`. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to flatten drives array in order to iterate each drive, and then make API call to get each drive lat lon.

You can achieve such thing with `mergeAll` and `mergeMap` operators.
Your code should look something like this:

```js
fetchDrives().pipe(
  mergeAll(), // Flatten the drives array
  mergeMap(drive => getLatLong(drive)) // Get each drive { lat, lon }
).subscribe(console.log)
```

You can run the full example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ytrksi?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: It printed the console thrice within the subscription, I wanted to have it only once with an array of objects containing lat lon